# upgrading from primefaces 4.0 to 5.0 problems

Tags: eclipse, primefaces

I have a dynamic web project in eclipse running on Glassfish.

It was running fine on Primefaces 4.0 but I wanted to upgrade to 5.0 to use some of the new features. I deleted the "primefaces-4.0-jar" file and copied "primefaces-5.0.jar" into WEB-INF -> lib.

But when i run the project i get the error:
`org.primefaces.config.ConfigContainer.isTransformMetadataEnabled()Z`

I tired cleaning the project and restarting the server. I noticed on the console it still says the project is running version 4.0. 
Is there a file or some project setting i need to change in order for the project to run with 5.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem when trying to update my Primefaces from 4.0 to 5.0 (on a Netbeans project). I first tried to "Add JAR to project", and I got the same error than you. What I've done is Right-click on "Librairies", then "Properties".

Jump to "Frameworks", then on the "Components" tab, click "More". Netbeans offers you then to create a new library. I added "primefaces-5.0.jar" to this newly created library, and validated. After that, you can right-click again on "Librairies" on your project, then select "Add library". You can see your custom library on the list. Select it, then validate.

After those steps, I restarted my server, re-deployed my app, and everything was working fine.
I still can't understand why adding the .jar didn't work in the first place though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I eventually got mine working after playing around for a while.

To get mine working I removed the project from Glassfish, then restarted glassfish added the project back and validated/published to the server and it worked.

yes it is very strange that you would need to play around with settings just to update a jar file. But least its working now, I will leave this post up incase someone else experiences the same problem

Answer (score 1):

There might be multiple Primefaces Jar(say 4.0 and 5.0). Remove the old one and keep the latest one.
This worked for  me.